# Exit remote python program when ssh connection closes

Tags: python, ssh

I'm writing a python program to run on a remote machine.

When I execute the program on the remote machine like this.

`ssh remotemachine foo.py`

and I stop the ssh connection with CTRL-c the program keeps running for sometime.

I know I can start the ssh connection with a pseudo terminal like this.

`ssh -t remotemachine foo.py`

Then the program will catch the CTRL-c event and I can handle it in the program. But I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Unless foo.py double-forks, it should be killed with your ssh session. Are you sure it is still running after you hit CTRL-C ?

Comment: yes it's still running, but after a few minutes it stops. I did some further research and when an ssh session closes the sshd deamon sends an SIGHUP signal to the child programs. But this is with an delay. I want my remote program to detect when the ssh connection is closed.

Comment: Does a thread count as a double fork?

Answer (score 0):

you can get pid of instance of this app/script and send kill command